# Powershell - Capturing all lines between two values and saving the Captured lines to a file that Excel can read

Tags: powershell

I need to capture the data for every line that has an "*" in position 7 between IDENTIFICATION DIVISION and ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
All other data can be ignored and once I hit Environment division I can exit the file.

IDENTIFICATION DIVISION and ENVIRONMENT DIVISION both start in position 8.

Here is an example of my DATA

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
  ****************************************************************  00000700
  ****************************************************************  00000800
  * PURPOSE:  TO PERFORM THE I/O LOGIC TO RETRIEVE THE CREDITING *  00000900
  *           AGENTS FOR THE SPLIT AGREEMENTS FOR A CUSTOMER     *  00001000
  *           OR TERRITORY.                                      *  00001100
  *           CUSTOMIZED VERSION OF ADMLR301 FOR MONTHLY DST     *  00001110
  *           PROCESS-AAGYZ105.                                  *  00001110
  ****************************************************************  00001300
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
```

Here is code from @Olaf below.  I added the logic to create add and close an excel spreadsheet.  Works well!

Thank you @Olaf!!!

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$excel.visible = $False
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
$diskSpacewksht= $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$diskSpacewksht.Name = "CAPTURE"
$col1=3
$diskSpacewksht.Cells.Item(2,8) = 'Header - Deletes'
$diskSpacewksht.Cells.Item(3,1) = 'Program'
$diskSpacewksht.Cells.Item(3,2) = 'Description'

$CBLFileList = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\TEMP' -Filter '*.cbl' -File -Recurse
$Flowerbox = @()

ForEach($CBLFile in $CBLFileList) {
    Write-Host "Processing ... $CBLFile" -foregroundcolor green      
    Get-content -Path $CBLFile.FullName |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ -match 'IDENTIFICATION DIVISION') {
            $treat = $true
        }
        if ($_ -match 'ENVIRONMENT DIVISION') {
             $col1++
             $diskSpacewksht.Cells.Item($col1,1) = $CBLFile
             $diskSpacewksht.Cells.Item($col1,2) = [String]$Flowerbox
             $Flowerbox = @()
             continue
        }
        if ($treat) {
            if ($_ -match '\*(.{60})') {
                Foreach-Object {$Flowerbox += $matches[1] + "`r`n"}
            }
        }

    }
   
}

$excel.DisplayAlerts = 'False'
$ext=".xlsx"
$path="C:\MISC\CAPTURE$ext"
$workbook.SaveAs($path) 
$workbook.Close
$excel.DisplayAlerts = 'False'
$excel.Quit()
```

Comment: Hi @Olaf,  I'm trying to capture the Flower box and all it's contents.  Those are the comments for each program.  Pretty much what the program does.  I have 25K programs.  I'm trying to avoid editing each one and Copy/Paste the flowerbox into an Excel Spreadsheet.

Comment: What do you mean by _"position 7"_ ? is that the line number or the character position as counted from the beginning of the line? Please show us the **exact** desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input file always has the format you showed in the snippet your task might be easier than you think:  ;-)

```
$CBLFileList = 
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\sample' -Filter '*.cbl' -File -Recurse
$output = 
ForEach($CBLFile in $CBLFileList) {
    Get-content -Path $CBLFile.FullName |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ -match 'IDENTIFICATION DIVISION') {
            $treat = $true
        }
        if ($_ -match 'ENVIRONMENT DIVISION\.') {
            continue
        }
        if ($treat) {
            if ($_ -match '\*\s(.{60})') {
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Path = $CBLFile.FullName
                    Catch = $Matches[1]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
$output
```

The code ignores all lines of the input file until it hits the first line with 'IDENTIFICATION DIVISION' then parses all lines until it hits the first line with 'ENVIRONMENT DIVISION'.

That should output what you're after. I just don't think it would be a good idea to pipe it to a CSV file.

The regex is looking for some arbitrary charachters following a single asterisk followed by one or more white spaces and followed by one or more white spaces followed by a single asterisk.

Comment: Hi @Olaf,  I do not want the line numbers outside the flower box.  I want the flowerbox and its contents.  If I have to capture the line numbers, so be it.

Comment: That looks like what I want, Thank you!! - I'm just having trouble parsing your code into a Recursive search for all files in my directories.  Once I can figure that out - I then have to figure out how to export it to CSV.

Comment: I think your code might be overkill.  I just need the flowerbox between the two match cases.  I think your code gets me all the flowerboxes in the whole file.

Comment: Hi @Olaf - That code yielded zero results.  By that I mean my screen just printed the code and ended at the command line.

Comment: When I step through the code it looks like it wants to do things the right way but not - if that makes any sense

Comment: that code is very elegant.  If a line matches it sets the flag treat to true - do I have to reset the flag to false?

Comment: Ok - The code above is not stepping through the directory.  I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: The Break statement is exiting out of both loops not just the sub-loop.  Is that normal? Also the Capture Code for any Data inside the flowerbox is not capturing anything, I do not now Regex at all and that's adding a layer of complexity.

Comment: I think I figured out the break issue.  I needed a {return} instead.  At least I think that is working.  The Capture statement is still not working.

Comment: OK, this is working to escape the inner-loop.  I replaced the break with $treat = $false.  The Capture statement is still not working.

Comment: That works Great!!!  The files are not all the same.  They ALL start with an "*" but not all of them have an ending "*".  Is it possible to capture just the text after the "*" and ignore any text after position 72?

Comment: @user3166462 So your input files do not look like you showed initially  ;-)  .... ok, but that way you catch a lot of white space ... if I counted right you'd need to change this `'\*\s+(.+)\s+\*'` into this `'\*\s(.{60})'`

Comment: Holy Crud! That did it!!   Now I just need to figure a way to get that information into a spreadsheet.  Not to pile on - cuz you really did help me allot, but would you have a way to send this to a spread sheet?  Like column 1 has the file name and column 2 has everything you captured in it?  I think I have some code I've been playing with to create a spreadsheet, should I start another thread or discus it here?

Comment: Hmmm ... I'd consider a CSV in this case not as a proper output format. But anyway .. try if you like it that way.

Comment: The Capture script has a small flaw in it.  It bypasses any data that does not have a space separating the "*" and the data ---  Data like this "*  Capture me"  is fine but Data like this "*Capture me" or "*** Capture me" or "*== Capture me" is not captured.  Is there a way to just take everything after the first "*" un to position 72?

Comment: There is no copyright on this code.  ;-)  You can change it to your requirements ... and you should. The code I posted is just a suggestion. I explained in my answer what it captures ... a star/asterisk `*`  followed by a white space ` ` and followed by 60 random charachters ... that's what I counted in your example text. If you don't want to capture the white space remove `\s` from the pattern. If you need more than 60 charachters change the number in the pattern.

Comment: That worked and I added the code to send everything to two columns in Excel.  Column "A" has the File name and Column "B" has the data from your capture logic.  Thank you so much for all your help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
Clear-Host
$StringData = '
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
  ****************************************************************  00000700
  ****************************************************************  00000800
  * PURPOSE:  TO PERFORM THE I/O LOGIC TO RETRIEVE THE CREDITING *  00000900
  *           AGENTS FOR THE SPLIT AGREEMENTS FOR A CUSTOMER     *  00001000
  *           OR TERRITORY.                                      *  00001100
  *           CUSTOMIZED VERSION OF ADMLR301 FOR MONTHLY DST     *  00001110
  *           PROCESS-AAGYZ105.                                  *  00001110
  ****************************************************************  00001300
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
'  
[regex]::Match($StringData, '(?is)(?<=\bIDENTIFICATION DIVISION\b.).*?(?=\bENVIRONMENT DIVISION\b)').Value

# Results
<#
  ****************************************************************  00000700
  ****************************************************************  00000800
  * PURPOSE:  TO PERFORM THE I/O LOGIC TO RETRIEVE THE CREDITING *  00000900
  *           AGENTS FOR THE SPLIT AGREEMENTS FOR A CUSTOMER     *  00001000
  *           OR TERRITORY.                                      *  00001100
  *           CUSTOMIZED VERSION OF ADMLR301 FOR MONTHLY DST     *  00001110
  *           PROCESS-AAGYZ105.                                  *  00001110
  ****************************************************************  00001300
#>
```